# Magento setBeforeAuthUrl() redirects me to port 82

Tags: magento, redirect

I want the customer to be redirected to a certain page after logging in.

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); ?>
<p><a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl() ?>">Login</a>
```

The URL after redirection is fine, except for one detail:

http://mymagentostore.com:82/rest/of/url/

instead of

http://mymagentostore.com/rest/of/url/

Which results in a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused this, although I used a workaround like in example below and it worked

```
  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('part/of/url', array('param1' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1'))));
```